# Only backpropagate up to a given variable

Tags: pytorch

I’m working on a GAN where the discriminator operates on the latent space vector produced by the encoder. The details aren’t important, but the paper describing the model is https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.00409 if you want to take a look.

Essentially, my problem is that my training code requires an unnecessary backward pass through the encoder and I’m not sure how to get around this such that it becomes optimal. Here is the relevant code, where `E` is the encoder and `D` is the discriminator.

```
latent_vec = E(input) #latent_vector will be a Variable with requires_grad=True
predictions = D(latent_vec)

e_loss = encoder_loss(predictions, ground_truth)
e_optimizer.zero_grad()
e_loss.backward() #backpropagates through both D and E, which is necessary
e_optimizer.step()

d_loss = discriminator_loss(predictions, ground_truth)
d_optimizer.zero_grad()
d_loss.backward() #backpropagates through D, but also through E unnecessarily
d_optimizer.step()
```

This still works because the optimizers are only modifying the parameters of their respective models, but it’s inefficient because `d_loss.backward()` unnecessarily backpropagates through `E`. I’m aware that I can recreate a version of `latent_vec` that will prevent backpropagation through `E` using 
`latent_vec_no_grad = Variable(latent_vec.data)`, but then I would be stuck with 2 forward passes through `D` (one with `latent_vec` so that `e_loss` backpropagates through `E`, and one with `latent_vec_no_grad` so that `d_loss` only backpropagates through `D`).

Ideally, a flag such as `latent_vec.block_backprop = True` could be set after optimizing `E`, but no such flag exists. Is there an elegant solution that would make training optimal?

Comment: you are looking for `detach_()`. see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/dcgan/main.py#L235).

Comment: Although this gets rid of the unnecessary backward pass through E, it requires an unnecessary extra forward pass through the discriminator. One for `output = netD(fake.detach())` at line 235 and then another for `output = netD(fake)` at line 247. It is the same problem that I pointed out in my original question with `latent_vec_no_grad = Variable(latent_vec.data)`.